# Somers's C with ctree() of the R package party

Tags: r, party

I have seen a few articles around that report Somer's Dxy and the  C index (I presume with the somers2() function of e.g., Hmisc) for a conditional inference tree generated with ctree() from the R package party. However, I can't seem to find any references/guidelines as to how to compute Dxy and the C index for this function.

Could anyone provide me with some references/code to pull this off?

Thanks,

Jeroen Claes

Comment: I'm familiar with Somers-D and the c-index, but don't know what is meant by Somers-C. If the c-index is needed: If you look at the code of `Hmisc::somers` you see this line: `dxy <- 2 * (c.index - 0.5)`. Any high-school student should be able to perform the inverse operation.

Comment: Yes I would like to learn how to compute  the C index for a conditional inference tree. The thing is that you cannot just do somers2(ctree.model).

Comment: So you have no idea whether `somers2` can be applied to your problem and you're not even posing a real problem ... meaning data and an algorithm? Doesn't sound like a coding question.

Comment: That is not the issue. I know somers2 can be applied here because I have seen people apply somers2 to party trees in articles. I just don't know the code to do it and I'm asking you guys if you do know the code and are willing to share.

Comment: This forum expects you to first  post sample data and code to create a tree using the particular package. (Not all problems are going to have the binary response required for Somers D.)

Answer (score 1):

You can find how to do it in [Levshina](https://pure.mpg.de/rest/items/item_3253245_4/component/file_3393904/content), page 633.

Example code using the data in that page:

```
#create a vector of predicted probabilities

prob.cit <- unlist(predict(tv.cit, type = "prob"))

               [c(FALSE,TRUE)]
#compute the C-index using a function from the Hmisc package

somers2(prob.cit, as.numeric(tv$Form) - 1)
```